# How do I add a field in the SAP B1 Crystal Reports Field Explorer

Tags: crystal-reports, sapb1

I inherited a Crystal Report to modify. I need to add a table field in the Field Explorer so I can use in the report. Inside the Field Explorer, I have Command below Database Fields.

[image]

If I expand the Command, I see the fields that can be added to the report. How do I add the fields?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the query in the command returns the fields in the field explorer. Fields that I needed to the report were added to the command select query